# Setting an output parameter to the value of count() in sql stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, output-parameter

I have an output parameter `@Counter` and a temporary table `#tmpUsers`

Is it possible to assign the value of

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #tmpUsers
```

To the `@Counter` output parameter?

I have tried

```
SET @Counter = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #tmpUsers
```

But this doesn't work for me

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this way:

```
SELECT @Counter = COUNT(*) 
FROM #tmpUsers
```

or

```
SET @Counter = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #tmpUsers)
```